# In android I'm trying to figure out how to build a countdowntimer

Tags: android

that sets itself from the system clock.  a countdown of time until 2am the next day. say it's 11pm when you start the app. run a 3 hour countdown on the main.xml  this is what I have so far

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.app.Activity;

public class LastCall extends Activity {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();


      int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
      int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
      int timelefthour = 0;
      int timeleftmin = 0;



      if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 1 && hour != 12)

                timelefthour = (12 - hour) + 2;
                timeleftmin = 60 - minute;

      if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 1 && hour == 12)

                    timelefthour = 13;
                    timeleftmin = 60 - minute;          

      if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0 && hour == 12)

                timelefthour = 1;
                timeleftmin = 60 - minute;  

      if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0 && hour <= 2)

                timelefthour = 2 - hour;
                timeleftmin = 60 - minute;

       String lastcall = (Integer.toString(timelefthour) + " hr " + Integer.toString(timeleftmin) + " min ");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you are very incorrectly using the Activity class.

I would suggest you have a read of this page and then re-think your approach:

[Android Reference - Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

You don't use the main method for execution in an Android app.

Answer (score 1):

The typical Android Activity class will look something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //This is where you could create all of your objects etc...
    }

    private void MyMethod() {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

That is a typical activity.  The setContentView sets the screen to a pre formatted xml layout.  You probably want to create your objects, etc., inside the onCreate function, which is called at the start of an activity.

First I would suggest reading over the basics of the Android Activity class, and maybe making a HelloWorld app to get started.  Also, if you are not already, Android Dev is much easier if you use an nice IDE, such as Eclipse.  The IDE will do a lot of the manual stuff for you and you can just focus on coding.

Here is a nice link:  http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html